# Why is the Marketing Cloud barcodeURL with different

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, barcode

I am using the Marketing Cloud barcodeURL ampscript function. This is the script I am using:

```
%%[
/*Sets the scannable barcode */ 
var @barcodeImage, @zero
set @zero = "0"
set @barcodeFull = Concat(@zero, "", @barcode)
set @barcodeImage = BarcodeURL(@barcodeFull, "Code128A", 400,100 )
]%%
```

I have to set a zero because of the system that needs to scan the barcode. This works, only the width of the barcode does not match my settings. It looks like it is cropped or something. I am using a 15/16 character barcode. If I use less characters say for example 7 characters then it is going fine. I have no clue why this is happening. The tipping point seems to be around 11 characters.

Answer (score 0):

The [ampscript.guide](https://ampscript.guide/barcodeurl/) mentions the following:

> NOTE: Mat25, OneCode, PlainText , Planet, Postnet and Telepen
> symbologies do not render properly in the current release of
> Salesforce Marketing Cloud. This should be resolved in a future
> release.

However upon testing various barcodes, I’ve noticed that many of them do not render properly and it doesn’t seem that Salesforce is planning to fix it anytime soon (or at all).

I’d open a support case to double-check, but most likely this problem is not related to your code, rather related to the imperfection of the BarcodeURL function.